# How does @observable work under the hood in MobX?

Tags: javascript, mobx

What do the observables really look like under the hood? How does a property become observable and what does that really mean? Can't find a clear explanation that doesn't use ES.next decorators. Thanks!

Comment: The code is very well written and documented, so you could just read the code on GitHub. I also like this [**blog post**](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254#.a1t9xw4pw) on the matter.

Comment: I found reproducing of mobx's observer HOC in this post - https://teletype.in/@alteregor/mobx-50-loc

Answer (score 1):

See these two links    : https://medium.com/@mweststrate/becoming-fully-reactive-an-in-depth-explanation-of-mobservable-55995262a254 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfxfRkNCnmk